# Is there a better way to check if a collection is empty before a foreach in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, foreach, powershell-2.0

I have part of a deploy **PowerShell 2.0** script that copy a potential robots.dev.txt to robots.txt, if it doesn't exist don't do anything.

**My original code was:**

```
$RobotFilesToOverWrite= Get-ChildItem -Path $tempExtractionDirectory -Recurse -Include "robots.$Environment.txt"
    foreach($file in $RobotFilesToOverWrite)
    {
        $origin=$file
        $destination=$file -replace ".$Environment.","."

        #Copy-Item $origin $destination
    }
```

But, in a difference with C#, even if $RobotFilesToOverWrite is null, code is entering in the foreach.

So I had to surround everything with:

```
if($RobotFilesToOverWrite)
{
    ...
}
```

**This is the final code:**

```
$RobotFilesToOverWrite= Get-ChildItem -Path $tempExtractionDirectory -Recurse -Include "robots.$Environment.txt"
if($RobotFilesToOverWrite)
{
    foreach($file in $RobotFilesToOverWrite)
    {
        $origin=$file
        $destination=$file -replace ".$Environment.","."

        #Copy-Item $origin $destination
    }
}
```

**I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve that?**

**EDIT: This problem seems to be fixed in PowerShell 3.0**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# one way is using @(), it ensures an array always, i.e. empty instead of null
$RobotFilesToOverWrite = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $tempExtractionDirectory -Recurse -Include "robots.$Environment.txt")
foreach($file in $RobotFilesToOverWrite)
{
    ...
}

# another way (if possible) is not to use an intermediate variable
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $tempExtractionDirectory -Recurse -Include "robots.$Environment.txt")
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Tested foreach() with the the @() array forcing and works like OP is requesting.

Answer (score 6):

quote from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx

> ForEach statement does not iterate over $null

In PowerShell V2.0, people were often surprised by:

PS> foreach ($i in $null) { 'got here' } 
got here

This situation often comes up when a cmdlet doesn’t return any objects.  In PowerShell V3.0, you don’t need to add an if statement to avoid iterating over $null.  We take care of that for you.

Comment: I submitted the bug that this language change resolves back in June of 2007.  It took a while but they finally acknowledged it as undesirable behavior (which itself took a while) and then fixed it.  :-)  https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/281908/foreach-should-not-execute-the-loop-body-for-a-scalar-value-of-null

Comment: really nice bug submition with remarks full of infos ;) Hats off!

Comment: +1: Nice information. I am editing my question to clarify it is **PowerShell v2.0**